# Не срабатывает .ajax

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, из-за чего не работает javascript?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#histogram').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'action.php?plot=histogram',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET'
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            alert("check!");
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
    });
});
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="root">
            <form action="newresults.php" id="form" method="post">
                <input type="submit" name="histogram" value="histogram" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

В action.php передается JSON, вроде все как надо...

Comment: что вы ожидаете? и что получаете?

Comment: Почитал вопросы автора. Автор, не пробовал обращаться к документации и внимательно читать её? Большинство ошибок решается таким образом, а не написанием вопросов по каждой мелочи на stackoverflow

Comment: только начал программировать, учту...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#histogram')` нет такого элемента

Вот так нужно `<input type="submit" name="histogram" id="histogram" value="histogram" />`